# Where to ask non-programming related questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As I understand the Magento SE is for programming related questions, however I have seen many highly upvoted questions related certification and related study material, but I am not really sure.

Also, can I specifically ask moderators to protect a question?

Comment: Just for completeness: There's also a Q&A for questions about software development methods and practices (not specifically Magento or certifications): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento is a vast platform and there are lots of other aspects other than programming. This is a dedicated platform where we can ask questions about anything related to Magento.

### Some History..

We were using stackoverflow in the past to ask questions about Magento before. But soon enough most of the questions which were asking in stackoverflow becomes out of topic. This is simply because stackoverflow is a dedicated platform for asking only programming questions. But the very nature of Magento is not so. Developers troubled with lots of other aspects such as how to fine-tune Magento, how to improve the speed and performance, how to fine tune cache etc. These questions are not suited in StackOverflow. This is what leads to the proposal of Magento stack exchange site by Ben Marks. The purpose is, the Magento community needs clarification on lots of subjects other than programming and hence we needed a dedicated platform for that.

That's how the history goes... After that, there was time, people continue to use StackOverflow for asking programming related questions and for other questions, they rely on the Magento StackExchange.

### What can you ask here?

The answer is anything related to Magento.

Here is the [on-topic link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what should avoid here link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Feel free to go through it and understand it.

Comment: well said about `history` , can you tell something about `geography` also :)

Comment: wow! , nice explaination ,  seems like you are master in both `social studies` & `magento` :)

Answer (score 7):

The primary goal of this forum is indeed programming questions. But non-programming related is ok as well. Since it's a public forum the users basically decide what is desired or not.

You can always ask moderators to protect a question but there would have to be very special circumstances for that. It means a question is unpopular with the users but holds some special value.

Comment: Did you mean "But *non -* programming related is ok as well. "

Comment: @VivekKumar ah yeah I did, sorry bout that

Answer (score 2):

@Vivek Kumar, Yes, we can allow those which has a good value.

As a community, we should allow those questions/answers which contributes good value to the community and its engagements. So a question is not necessary to relate to programming every time.

To community respective, those exception giving profit to community user. In my view, if the user gives profit and it does not harm the community then we should allow.

Regarding protect those questions, you can ask the moderator.So, please share the links with us, we will protect if it in case it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked 2-3 question like that,

But my intention to ask those question is, if some has good content then they can share.

and Magento SE has good SEO , so if some one has similar kind of question for the exam or any query then they can easily get their answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need a special forum to share/ask the non-programming question related to Magento SE.

I found many helpful questions and same time amazing out of the scope answers which help users to know in depth of that topic as a theory or tricks or the issues which one found is also a part of development which not only saves other developer times but also give him more time to do some other productive things

As it is related to Magento it must be on Magento SE.